# Doxygen interpreting C code as C++

Tags: doxygen

Im using doxygen 1.8.6 on trusty. The problem is that it shows no content at all except for structs. No functions or variables. It also includes *Classes* tab in the html output which is for cpp. How can i tell doxygen to interpret my code as C code?

Comment: Have you tried setting EXTRACT_ALL to YES?

Comment: @Markuu K. I tried it now. It added the c files and the function definitions were included. But still no documentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing special needed to make doxygen parse C code. You can optimize the output for C though by setting `OPTIMIZE_OUTPUT_FOR_C` to `YES` in the config file.

For documentation to be picked up by doxygen, you need to use one of the special comment styles: `/** ..*/` or `/*! ... */`.

Comment: Yes you are right. i had spaces between the initial ** . Thanks

Comment: What about the name Classes in the menu tabs? that is quite confusing for non OOP languages.

Comment: That's what the OPTIMIZE_OUTPUT_FOR_C option is for.

Comment: @doxygen: Even with OPTIMIZE_OUTPUT_FOR_C, I find that the result is not as C-ish as I'd wish. For example, in the todo/deprecated/bug/test lists, function names have "Global" instead of their return type. It's true they are global, but in C everything is global because there are no namespaces. Omitting the return type is bad style even if it's just in such todo/deprecated/bug/tests lists. And then putting "Global" instead of the return type, makes it look really weird: nobody would document C like that if it was manually written.